# Объединение массива из base64 в один PDF файл

Tags: node.js, pdf

Есть массив из 4-х элементов - строк base64;
Нужно все это объединить в один pdf.

Как вариант, можно сохранить это в 4 отдельных файла, а потом объединить в один pdf.

Как можно объединить сразу содержимое base64 в один pdf, не создавая по десять раз разные файлы?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101395/merging-pdfs-in-node

Comment: Мне помогло решение с "hummus" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766234/nodejs-merge-two-pdf-files-into-one-using-the-buffer-obtained-by-reading-them/50063545#50063545

Comment: здорово. теперь будет хорошо если ты сформулируешь и напишешь ответ.